# Laravel Shared Hosting .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel

I am trying to deploy a Laravel project onto a share hosting, I've managed to get most of the hard work done but I cannot strip off the /public directory without a Forbidden issue.

The website works and shows same pages for these links

- www.mywebsite.com/test/index.php
- www.mywebsite.com/test/public/

But without the /index.php It returns ->

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /test/ on this server.
```

Currently my .htaccess looks like the following.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So `www.mywebsite.com/test/public/` works but `www.mywebsite.com/test/` doesn't?

Comment: www.mywebsite.com/test/index.php works though, so I believe something incorrect with my .htaccess

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this rule in `test/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /test/

    RewriteRule ^$ public/index.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply :) This kind-of works it produces a NotFoundHttpException where as index.php displays the website?

Comment: Yes but www.mywebsite.com/test/index.php works and also www.mywebsite.com/test/public works

Comment: Not Found - The requested URL /test/index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: Would team-viewer be easier?

Comment: Same again unfortunately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58612/discussion-between-anubhava-and-brent).

Answer (score 18):

this is the magic script i use (add to the `.htaccess` in `public_html`)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. Tried lot of things. Nothing worked.

Comment: If on a web server it is not working, then add RewriteBase like this                                                 `RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 4):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ public/index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This looks very similar to the top answer. Why do it this way?

Answer (score 0):

This script is working for me.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   # Force SSL
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
   # Remove public folder form URL
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```