# Migrating laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I created laravel project on localhost, everything is working fine, but now I want to move it to my hosting (I dont have shell access, ftp only). When I copied all project files, on '/' request I got 'Access forbidden', so i created .htaccess file with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And now it works, but when I request for '/user' I'm redirected to '/public/user', why? And how to repair it?
My route:

```
Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('login-example');
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Shared Hosting .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119493/laravel-shared-hosting-htaccess), basically, you need to specify the index file as the entry point

Comment: It only works for '403 Forbidden error' but from /login I'm still redirected to /public/login.. :/

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/bladeSk/3666d04964e4de9c263776ba51f33a18

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work with this .htaccess